# Web Service in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to print out all number from 1 to 1,000,000 with 1,000 numbers per line. and return the response without having a long delay.

Thanks in advance for any type of help!!!

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Your question is far too broad for the rules of stack overflow.  We don't just write a whole server for you on demand.  After you do some research on your own, we are here to answer specific questions, not wildly broad questions.  Specific questions often go like this: "I'm trying to do X.  I've read that I need to write code like this (include your code in your question), but I got stuck on Z.  Does anyone know why <some specific question about your code>?

Comment: I want to print all number from 1 to 1000000 with 1000 numbers per line after saving it to file return response to user when whole process is done.

Comment: have you tried any code for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you can create a function to print numbers from 1 to 1000.

```
function getThousand(index) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = index; i < index + 1000; i++) {
    result += i + ' ';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then, you need a function to call this for 1 to 1000000.

```
function getAll() {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    result = getThousand((i * 1000) + 1) + " \n";
    fs.appendFileSync('foo.txt', result);
  }
}
```

Then call it all:

```
getAll();
```

This will save your lines into a file. At the end of `getAll()` you can print what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...main part in which i am stuck is saving the 1000 numbers in a line in the file  and after completion send the response to user.

Comment: You could have started the question from here and prompt some code. What did you try already, can we have your code?

Comment: How about if i use writeStream.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really work with files, so I don't know the best / fastest function for writing into files. You may ask this specific question on StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: Thanks...that's what i also did....i am using writestream but the only case is its not sending response to user...As you are using sync function.

Comment: I see, I used a sync function because of lazyness.